# “Babrahams Transaction” does library has timeout feature?

Tags: meteor, transactions, angular-meteor

We are using babrahams:transaction library in our project. We have business case where we need to add timeout as part of transaction commit(tx.commit()). If transaction is taking more that x milliseconds to complete all queries to commit, then it should rollback all the changes.

Please let me know whether this can be achieved using  babrahams:transaction library?
If not, can this be achieved logically in meteor code?

Ref:
Git Hub : https://github.com/JackAdams/meteor-transactions
Library : https://atmospherejs.com/babrahams/transactions

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the transaction part of a Meteor Method?

Comment: This is probably better raised as a question on the github issues for the package, as I doubt it will be general knowledge

Comment: @Mikkel Thanks for your suggestion. I will also post this query in babrahams:transaction github as a issue.